# How to render different JSONs from the same model in Java Play Framework 2.5.x?

Tags: java, model-view-controller, playframework, ebean

I have a model (entity bean) Bank Accounts with 4 fields:

1. Account Number.
2. Account Holder's Name.
3. CustomerID
4. GroupID

I have two different controllers that render the Account Number and Account Holder's Name in one view, and the CustomerID and GroupID in another view. But, when using `Json.toJson(bankAccountObject)` in my views, it returns all four fields including the null values. I cannot annotate these with @JsonIgnore because if I do it for one set of fields for one view the same becomes invisible to the other view. What would be the best way to selectively render model fields in my views and not show the null values?

Answer (score 0):

Use Jackson's [`JsonView`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.8/index.html?com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonIgnore.html) annotation as explained here:

http://www.baeldung.com/jackson-json-view-annotation

And to ignore null values:

http://www.baeldung.com/jackson-ignore-null-fields

But, keep in mind that if you want to heavily customized Jackson's `ObjectMapper` instantiation (for example to do something like `mapper.disable(MapperFeature.DEFAULT_VIEW_INCLUSION)`), then you need to disable the default one and create your own, as explained here:

https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/JavaJsonActions#Advanced-usage